# Make CSS style not possible to override and unique

Tags: css, overriding

Let's say I want to include my content to somebody elses site. Is there a way to make my style unique and cannot be overriden by his css files.

I have my content in a div with specific ID. If I write my css like this

```
#divId a {
color:red;
}
```

The link color can still be overriden by his style. I hope the question is understandable...

Answer (score 0):

```
#divId a {
  color:red !important;
}
```

This will give your style precedence, but if he later uses !important in his own style for the same element it will follow normal cascading rules and override yours.

Answer (score 0):

The Best would be if you would create different classes for action like this to not having trouble leater for example if you want some elements always red creade class like this :

```css
.always-red {
  
  color : red !important;
  
  }
```

And create different files for this called helpers or something else. so now if you would like some different elements always red you can use it simply like this :

```html
<div class="col-md-12 always-red">

  // Some html in here which text color will be always red
  
</div>
```